# How do I send diffrent values into two tables in db?

Tags: java, mysql

I have two tables called `addstudent` and `parent` which have same primary key as `sid` and `Sid` respectively (student ID). I use phpmyadmin.

I am entering values to a single form but values should be inserted into these two tables separately. That means student details into the `addstudent` table and guardian details into the `parent` table.

I have found some PHP code with transaction process:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO addstudent (sid, first_name, last_name) VALUES 
(no, fname, lname) ";
String q = "INSERT INTO parent (Sid, fathername,mothername)
VALUES (Sid,fn,mn)";

$result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result) {
   $verify=1;
}
else{
  $verify=0;
}
echo $verify;

mysqli_close($conn);
```

What I need to know is: what the is the purpose of the `$verify` part of the code?

I use the Java programming language. Do I need a transaction to handle this? Or how can I handle this?

Comment: i have not understood your question.

Comment: This is not a very good PHP code. The `$verify` variable seems to just be an indication if the query succeeded or not, and it's not really necessary. If you work with Java, you better forget this code, learn some JDBC, and work out your own code.

Comment: do i need a transaction to handle this?

Comment: It would be advisable to use transactions. If there was an issue with your first insert, any foreign key dependencies from the parent table to the addstudent table would fail. If you don't have foreign key dependencies, the second table would have invalid references that would likely cause further application problems and generally result in you having a corrupt data structure.

Comment: It is also generally advisable by todays standards to use PDO isntead of mysqli. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for help writing this type of transactional insert in Java and not in PHP?

Comment: ya..i want some help writing this type of transactional insert in java

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_multi_query returns false if the first statement fails. So in this case $result gonna be false, so $verify = 0, and it shows something went wrong.

Use of transaction:
If you have multiple queries and one of them fails (no matter why), then you can roll back your database to its previous state.

For example:
You have a table with one row of data. You'd like to insert two other rows. You insert the first successfuly, but your second insert fails. Now if you use transaction you can roll back the database, (now the magic part ->) so you have one row again.

Answer (score -1):

In your example, $verify is just used to show if the first query was successful.

Take a look at PHP documentation for PDO and transactions. There example very closely matches your use case.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Example from linked page:

```
   <?php
    try {
      $dbh = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2', 
          array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
      echo "Connected\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
    }

    try {  
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $dbh->beginTransaction();
      $dbh->exec("insert into staff (id, first, last) values (23, 'Joe', 'Bloggs')");
      $dbh->exec("insert into salarychange (id, amount, changedate) 
          values (23, 50000, NOW())");
      $dbh->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $dbh->rollBack();
      echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

Java documentation for JDBC transactions: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

```
Java code example from the linked site:

public void updateCoffeeSales(HashMap<String, Integer> salesForWeek)
    throws SQLException {

    PreparedStatement updateSales = null;
    PreparedStatement updateTotal = null;

    String updateString =
        "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
        "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";

    String updateStatement =
        "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
        "set TOTAL = TOTAL + ? " +
        "where COF_NAME = ?";

    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
        updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : salesForWeek.entrySet()) {
            updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
            updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
            updateSales.executeUpdate();
            updateTotal.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
            updateTotal.setString(2, e.getKey());
            updateTotal.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                con.rollback();
            } catch(SQLException excep) {
                JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(excep);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (updateSales != null) {
            updateSales.close();
        }
        if (updateTotal != null) {
            updateTotal.close();
        }
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
}
```